# how to hide firebase push notification foreground and background in iOS Swift?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

I am using firebase push notification iOS app, but in some condition we don't have to show push notification to user , only i have to use the data received along with push notification .

**Payload sent from server** :

```
{ 
to: iosTokenList[i],
  notification: {
   title: 'Hidden',
   body: "Hidden",
   Data: {
   "Id":Id,
   "someList":SomeList,
   "status": "inactive"
    },
  notificationType: "status"
},
```

**Problem**

When i am not sending `notification.title` and `notification.body`  then push notification in not received in ios app. No methods are getting called  in appDelegate ,

But when  we are adding  `notification.title=somevalue` and `notification.body=somevalue`  , `willPresent` is called .

**AppDelegate**

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        NotificationParser.parseIncommingMessages(notification: notification)
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        print("PushNotifications :  \(userInfo)")

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        }else{
            let dict = userInfo as NSDictionary
            if let alert = dict.value(forKeyPath: "aps.alert") as? String{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: appTitle  , message: alert + "didReceiveRemoteNotification", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                appDel.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```